# PHP MySQL Picture/Data Dynamic Alignment

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Morning all,

I'm having an alignment issue.

I am using a MYSQL array to create a sports profile page.

I want it to display the image, then to the right, show their name, position and number below each other.

Then i want it to dynamically display 3 or 4 of these next to each other before swapping down to the next line.

I have managed to get it to work with just the pictures, not with the text in between.  they all just show on new lines currently.

```
<style>
   #container .profile{
               display: inline-block;
               vertical-align:top;
                      }
</style>
<div class="profile">
<img src="wp-content/uploads/profile/jh7.jpg" alt="" /><br />
<h3 class="widget-title">Player 1</h3>
<p>Defence</br>#7</br></br>
<img src="wp-content/uploads/profile/dw21.jpg" alt="" /><br />
<h3 class="widget-title">Player 2</h3>
<p>Defence</br>#21</br></br>
<img src="wp-content/uploads/profile/pn22.jpg" alt="" /><br /> 
<h3 class="widget-title">Player 3</h3>
<p>Defence</br>#22</br></br>
</div>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->


</div>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: This is a CSS question. Please replace the PHP with the HTML that is outputted, and then remove the PHP and MySQL tags.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Although, to be fair, the OP might not have known that!

Answer (score 1):

Quick example : float the images and clear the float with a block element having a `clear: both` property :

http://jsfiddle.net/L8jtwkw1/2/

You can wrap each profile in a container and use inline block to list them horizontally then.

Comment: Well, that doesn't exactly put three to a row

Comment: Yeah, I think the OP's issue is about css formatting in general - but, getting three in a row in particular.

Comment: I need the text next to the picture, then the other pictures with text, to line horizontally

Comment: Edited my answer with an updated link to reflect what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use float left for the image:

```
<style>
    .profile img{
        float: left;
          margin-right: 5px;
    }    
  </style>
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/jigotamamu/1/

Comment: Thanks for that, that's almost cracked it.

Comment: I now have the text next to the pictures as desired. Can I get it so that there are 3 or 4 of these in a line rather than 1 on each row? Like columns on the page?

Comment: Sure, make them in a list and style it horizontally! i.e from your initial code, replace `<br />` with `<ul><li>Number</li><li>another</li>...</ul>`

Comment: I mean an inclusive set of image and the associated text, then another set etc, wouldn't listing horizontally just make the text go side by side?

Comment: Checkout this demo and place any html tags you want: http://jsbin.com/jigotamamu/2/edit

Comment: I have set `display: inline-block` for `li`

Comment: No, sorry, I want the text to stack vertically, but then have another picture to the right, with that players details to the right as well, I have managed to get it so that it stacks diagonally, I assume it's only down to a line break or similar

Answer (score 1):

It still didn't do exactly what I was after, However I managed to sort it by putting a column in:

```
<style> 
.profile img{ 
      float: left; 
      margin-right: 10px; 
      margin-top: 2px; } 
.profile h3 { display: inline-block; } 
.profile pos{ } 
.column-left{ float: left; width: 33%; } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that thie problem is in `<h3>` tag - you need either replace it with `<span>` or override styles for it.

For example:

```
echo '<img src="wp-content/uploads/profile/'.$row['Id'].'.jpg" alt="" />',
   '<span class="widget-title">'.$row['FirstName'].' '.$row['Surname'].'</span>',
    $row['PositionLong'].'</br>',
   '#'.$row['Number'].'</br>';
```

If you show the css styles for `widget-title`, we can help you.